# Error: variables specified with different types from the fit in shiny

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app which uses classification algorithm to predict a response variable. There is no problem with the model or the `predict` function when ran on R. However, incorporated in shiny, it gives the following error:

`Error: variables ‘X1’, ‘X2’, ‘X3’ were specified with different types from the fit.`

Here is the data I created to simplify the problem:

```
data1 <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(c("a","b"), 1000, rep = TRUE)),
                replicate(3, sample(0:1, 1000, rep = TRUE)))
colnames(data1)[1] <- "outcome"
```

where variable "outcome" is the response variable and "X1", "X2" and "X3" are the predictors.

The model I've trained is as following;

```
modelFit <- train(outcome ~ ., data  = data1, method  = "glm")
```

This is the Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(caret)
library(shinyapps)
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  modelFit <- readRDS("modelFit.Rds")    
  userdf <- data1[1,]
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- userdf
  newEntry <- observe({
    values$df$X1 <- input$X1
    values$df$X2 <- input$X2
    values$df$X3 <- input$X3})
  output$results <- renderPrint({
    ds1 <- values$df
    a <- predict(modelFit, newdata = data.frame(ds1))
    names(a) <- NULL
    cat(a)
  })
})
```

and the UI.R is

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                  @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Cabin:400,700');
                  h1 {
                  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
                  font-weight: 500;
                  line-height: 1.1;
                  color: #48ca3b;
                  }
                  "))
    ),
# Application title
  titlePanel(" Predictor",
           windowTitle = "random Predictor"),
  h5("Just for Fun"),

  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    hr(),
    h5('Enter parameters for prediction:'),
    hr(),
    selectInput("X1", 
                 label = h6("Numer of Bronze Badges"), 
                 choices = unique(data1$X1)),
    selectInput("X2", 
                 label = h6("Numer of Silver Badges"), 
                 choices  = unique(data1$X2)),
    selectInput("X3", 
                label = h6("Numer of blue Badges"), 
                choices  = unique(data1$X3))

  ),  #ends sidebarPanel

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Results", h2("The output is"),
               h2(verbatimTextOutput("results")),
               h2(" answers to your question."),
               p(), "Note:" , p(), "Look for it"))
      )
  )
))
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to coerce your `input$X`'s  to integer.

If you add `cat(str(input$X1))` to your `output$results` you immediately see that it is interpreted as character rather than an integer.

Simply add as. integer, e.g: `values$df$X1 <- as.integer(input$X1)` to make the predict function work again as expected.